# SSML or IPA TTS on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

o

I'm trying to make an app (for myself only) that will pronounce odd (fantasy) names properly.
I found chrome's TTS api and W3C's SpeechSynthesis API however it would appear that Chrome strips all SSML tags before speaking the remaining text:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis
                   http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/synthesis.xsd"
         xml:lang="en-US">
  <!-- Phoneme representation is cut short to exaggerate problem -->
  <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="t&#x259;mei&#x325;"> tomato </phoneme>
</speak>
```

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Griffork/7hgbzk2r/)

How can I get the SSML in that JSFiddle to be pronounced properly in Chrome?

- [Related Chromium Bug about TTS](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88072)
- [Resolved Chromium Bug about SpeechSynthesis (the fix was to strip SSML tags)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428902)

FYI I'm running windows so I can't use the mac-specific pronounication markup.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found mespeak (http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) but it doesn't support the phoneme tag.

Comment: SSML still hasn't been implemented: https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/10 , https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88072